# wget .vs curl using linux

Tags: linux, curl, wget

I'm running a test on linux using `wget`/`curl`. I can get `wget` to run, but I can't do the same thing with `curl`.

`wget` version:

```
 wget -v -O osu.tst  -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4'  'http://ohiostate.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBListView?catalogId=10001&storeId=33552&termMapping=N&courseXml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><textbookorder><courses><course dept="CHEM" num="100" sect="16030" term="S12" /></courses></textbookorder> '
```

`curl` version:

```
curl -v -b fftfcook -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4" -L  "http://ohiostate.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBListView?catalogId=10001&storeId=33552&termMapping=N&courseXml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><textbookorder><courses><course dept="CHEM" num="100" sect="16030" term="S12" /></courses></textbookorder>"
```

`curl` returns a partial page of content while `wget` gets what the browser generates. I've tried to modify the cookies/etc.. but `wget` is a straight "get" so it should work in `curl` as a straight get as well. the user agent is set to the same...

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Try single quotes around the URL, or escape the double quotes within it... or is that a typo?

Comment: ps.. already tried using single quotes around the url, as well as double quotes.. and escaping the inner double quotes in the url.. no difference

Comment: curl by default does not handle http redirect while wget does. Maybe the original url returns a redirection to the right content? In this case wget will get it, but not curl (unless you use -L option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the GET data is not URL-encoded.  Only a limited set of characters can appear in the URL or GET data without such encoding, though when entered into the browser's address bar the browser often handles this for you.

Rather than tacking the GET data onto the end of the URL, use the `-d` and `--data-urlencode` options for each value, and pass the `-G` option to treat these as GET data.  So you'd end up with the following:

```
curl -v -b fftfcook -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4" -L  'http://ohiostate.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBListView' -G -d 'catalogId=10001' -d 'storeId=33552' -d 'termMapping=N' --data-urlencode 'courseXml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><textbookorder><courses><course dept="CHEM" num="100" sect="16030" term="S12" /></courses></textbookorder>'
```

The various `-d` and `--data-urlencode` options will be joined together to form the GET data on the URL.  Note also the changes from double to single quotes, to prevent the double quotes in the form data from causing a problem.